# (c3.js) how to capture a column state, wheter it's shown or not in the graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I would expect **shown** to be some *boolean* type return, so I could write something like that:

```
if(!(chart.data('data1').shown)){ //if it's not (!) showing
    d3.select("elementID").text(""); //hide the matching text (see picture)
}
```

[image link (the graph i'm working on)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9WhS.png)

It doesn't work, but the console shows no errors, which is kinda' odd.

Is adding personal changes on the c3.js file the only solution?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect right, just use *.shown* as a function:

```
if(!(chart.data.shown('data1'))){
    d3.select("elementID").text("");
}
```

See [docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-data-shown) for more info.